# The permissions of a file won't change to the ones I want

Tags: linux, perl, file, permissions, mojolicious

I have this in my Mojolicious app:

```
  my $content = get_content();
  open my $fl, '>', $my_file_full_path
      or die $!;

  print $fl $content;
  close $fl;


  # change owner to my_user:my_user
  my $uid = getpwnam "my_user";
  my $gid = getgrnam "my_user";
  chown $uid, $gid, $my_file_full_path;

  # change permissions
  chmod 0777, $my_file_full_path;
```

However, in the end, the permissions of a newly created file still will remain `rwxr-xr-x` and that's not 777

How to fix that? Why is that in the first place?

Comment: Do you have checks to see if those chown and chmod calls succeed?

Comment: is the user that this script is run as, the owner of that file as well?

Comment: chown will fail unless ran by root

Comment: @the.Legend I know

Comment: @GerhardBarnard it's root

Comment: What does chmod returns? What happens if the same chmod is done in the shell directly by the same user?

Comment: Check the  umask settings (run `umask` in a shell) of the user that runs the app. If they don't match your requirements you can override them with Perl's core function [umask](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `$!` variable to see the error for a system call:

```
chmod 0777, $my_file_full_path 
      or warn "Could not chmod for $my_file_full_path: $!";
```

Once you tell us that answer we can see about fixing it.